# помогите составить запрос выборки из mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Всем доброго настроения! Я учусь, не пинайте )
Помогите составить запрос mysql

Имеется табл, в которой колонки start_date и start_time

я делаю выборку

```
SELECT * FROM history WHERE start_date BETWEEN '$start_date' AND '$stop_date'
```

как изменить запрос, чтобы еще и время в сортировки участвовало?

Comment: Вам надо хранить дату-время в одной колонке типа datetime

Comment: тогда все остальное надо будет переписывать )

Comment: Да, но иногда еще удобно хранить в UNIX секундах `INT(11)` которые просто получить функцией `time()` и затем конвертировать в `date()` при отображении.

Comment: какой тип данных имеет колонка `start_date` ?

Comment: год-месяц-день   2017-01-20

Comment: покажите результат команды:  show create table history;

Comment: не знаю как это сделать )

Comment: Ну значит надо все переписать. Иначе дальше всю жизнь будете мучатся. полное условие у вас должно получаться типа "дата между датой начала+1 день и датой окончания-1 день ИЛИ (дата равна дате начала И время больше времени начала) ИЛИ (дата равна дате окончания И время меньше времени окончания). Хотя конечно из даты и времени можно concat() собрать одну строку и сравнивать ее. И в любом случае такой поиск - гарантированный перебор всей таблицы, что катастрофически скажется на производительности если таблица будет достаточно большой

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT
    *
FROM
    history
WHERE
        start_date
            BETWEEN
                '$start_date'
            AND
                '$stop_date'
    AND
        start_time
            BETWEEN
                '$start_time'
            AND
                '$stop_time';`

Но лучше последовать рекомендациям и переместить дату и время в одну колонку.

Остальное, что следует за этим кодом переписывать не прийдется т.к. Вы можете в select выбрать 2 раза одно поле datetime и привести его отдельно к date и отдельно к time задав им соответствующие алиасы.